# The requested module 'openai' does not provide an export named 'Configuration' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern, openai-api

I'm trying to build an AI image generating website using MERN and I got this error:

> The requested module 'openai' does not provide an export named
> 'Configuration'.
>
> file:///C:/Users/Rashmika%20Satish/ai_website/server/routes/dalleRoutes.js:3
> import {Configuration, OpenAIApi} from 'openai';
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: The requested module 'openai' does not provide an export named 'Configuration'
> at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
> at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)
>
> Node.js v18.15.0 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes
> before starting...

this is the dalleRoutes.js page:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {Configuration, OpenAIApi} from 'openai';



dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();
```

This is the index.js page:

```
import express from 'express'
import *  as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';

import connectDB from './mongodb/connect.js';

import postRoutes from './routes/postRoutes.js';
import dalleRoutes from './routes/dalleRoutes.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use('/api/v1/post', postRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/dalle', dalleRoutes);

app.get('/', async(req, res)=>{
    res.send('Hello from CreateAI');
})

const startServer = async () =>{


    try{
        connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
        app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server has started on port http://localhost:8080'))
    }catch(error){
         console.log(error);
    }
    

}
startServer();
```

This is the postRoutes.js page

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary';

import Post from '../mongodb/models/post.js';

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got this same error. I'm assuming that you're following the JSM Tutorial to create the app. After a lot of searching, I finally found a similar discussion on the OpenAI Forum 5 days back, and it seems like it's a version change - configuring the api key has been simplified in v4.

Follow the Forum here, if you're interested: https://community.openai.com/t/getting-an-error-when-importing-configuration-and-openaiapi-from-openai/325012

Here's the Github Guide on Migrating from v3 to v4: https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217

In Short, just run `npm exec openai migrate` and it should automatically migrate and change the code in your codebase to the latest version and should fix this version issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
     apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY // This is also the default, can be omitted
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { OpenAI } from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY});
```

create .env file and paste your api key generated from https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

if you want to genarate images the,

```
const response = openai.images.generate();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Editing the import of OpenAI API key and the constant function did the trick for me.

```js
import { OpenAI } from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY });
```

It is a openai v4 change to the api hence this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import OpenAI from "openai";
```

This worked for me, if you are working on image generation using DallE (OpenAIv4)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for version 4

import { OpenAI } from "openai";
const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it makes a lot of sense why they did what they did.
if you're trying to create JSM DALL-E application & your openai version is 4.

```
"openai": "^4.29.2"
```

then this might help you.

upgrade code to

```
 import OpenAI from "openai";
 const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,});
```

from

```
const config = new Configuration({apiKey:process.env.OPENAPI_KEY}); 
const openai = new OpenAIApi(config);
```

Answer (score -1):

import OpenAI from "openai";

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you explain how this can address the question? Be sure to read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you